# double exp(double) unexpectedly returns NaN (no float overflow)

Tags: c++, double, overflow, nan, exp

I've been working on implementing black-body radiation according to Planck's law with the following:

```
double BlackBody(double T, double wavelength) {
  wavelength /= 1e9; // pre-scale wavelength to meters

  static const double h = 6.62606957e-34; // Planck constant
  static const double c = 299792458.0; // speed of light in vacuum
  static const double k = 1.3806488e-23; // Boltzmann constant

  double exparg = h*c / (k*wavelength*T);
  double exppart = std::exp(exparg) - 1.0;
  double constpart = (2.0*h*c*c);
  double powpart = pow(wavelength, -5.0);
  double v = constpart * powpart / exppart;
  return v;
}
```

I have a float[max-min+1] array, where static const int max=780, static const int min = 380. I simply iterate over the array, and put in what the BlackBody gives for the wavelength (wavelength = array-index + min). The IntensitySpectrum::BlackBody performs this iteration, while both min and max are static member vars, and the array is also inside IntensitySpectrum.

```
IntensitySpectrum spectrum;

Vec3 rgb = spectrum.ToRGB();
rgb /= std::max(rgb.x, std::max(rgb.y, rgb.z));
for (int xc = 0; xc < grapher.GetWidth(); xc++) {
  if (xc % 10 == 0) {
    spectrum.BlackBody(200.f + xc * 200.f);
    spectrum.Scale(1.0f / 1e+14f);
    rgb = spectrum.ToRGB();
    rgb /= std::max(rgb.x, std::max(rgb.y, rgb.z));
  }
  for (int yc = 20; yc < 40; yc++) {
    grapher(xc, yc) = grapher.FloatToUint(rgb.x, rgb.y, rgb.z);
  }
}
```

The problem is that, the line spectrum.BlackBody() sets the 0th element of the array to NaN, and only the 0th. Also it does not happen for the very first iteration, but all the following ones where xc>=10.

The text from the VS debugger:
spectrum = {intensity=0x009bec50 {-1.#IND0000, 520718784., 537559104., 554832896., 572547904., 590712128., 609333504., ...} }

I tracked the error down, and exppart in the ::BlackBody() function becomes NaN, basically exp() returns NaN, even though it's argument is near 2.0, so definetely not overflow. But only for array index 0. It magically starts working for the rest 400 indices.

I know memory overruns might cause things like that. That's why I double checked my memory handling.
I'm linking Vec3 from another self-made library, which is much bigger, and might contain errors, but what I use from Vec3 has nothing to do with memory.

After many hours I'm completely clueless. What else can cause this? Is the optimizer or WINAPI fooling me...? (Uhm, yes, the program creates a window, with WINAPI, and uses a nearly empty WndProc that calls my code on WM_PAINT.)

Thanks for you help in advance.

Sorry for making it unclear. This is the layout:

```
// member
class IntensitySpectrum {
public:
    void BlackBody(float temperature) {
        // ...
        this->intensity[i] = ::BlackBody(temperature, wavelength(i));
        // ...
    }
private:
    static const int min = 380;
    static const int max = 780;
    float intensity[max-min+1];
}

// global
double BlackBody(double T, double wavelength);
```

Comment: You showed `double BlackBody(double T, double wavelength)`, which apparently isn't what you are calling in the other block of code. There you are calling `IntensitySpectrum::BlackBody(float)` or `IntensitySpectrum::BlackBody(double)`. There is no second argument, and you are not using the return value from that function call.

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to be using MSVC 2013, one possible explanation is that you have some code somewhere that is trying to convert a float infinity to int.  A bug in MSVC 2013 causes an unbalanced push on the x87 FPU stack when this happens.  Trigger that bug 8 times and your FPU stack is totally full, and any subsequent attempt to push a value (such as calling 'exp()') will result in an 'invalid operation' and return an indefinite (like 1.#IND).  Note that even if you are compiling with SSE2 floating point instructions, this bug can still bite because the calling convention dictates that floating point return values are returned on the top of the FPU stack.

To check if this is your issue, have a look at your FPU registers just prior to the bad call to 'exp()'.  If your TAGS register is all zero, then your FPU stack is full.

- http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/806362/vc12-pollutes-the-floating-point-stack-when-casting-infinity-nan-to-unsigned-long

MS claims this will be fixed in update 2 for MSVC 2013.

Answer (score -1):

The following function call only has 1 parameter:

```
spectrum.BlackBody(200.f + xc * 200.f);
```

So it cannot be calling the function you defined as

```
double BlackBody(double T, double wavelength)
```

If you look at the `::BlackBody` implementation, I'm betting you have a divide by 0 error somewhere.

Comment: Those two "BlackBody"s are different functions, one is a member, that calls the other, which is global. I added a small code snippet for clarification.
Additionally, there's no divide by 0, it's specifically the exp() that return NaN.

Comment: @petiaccja What is the value of `wavelength` when you get the `NaN` result?

Comment: It goes from 380.0 (min) to 780.0 (max) in a loop. Then divided by 1e+9 in BlackBody to get metres, so 380e-9 to 780e-9 is used for exp(). 380 causes NaN, while 381 to 780 works perfectly.

Comment: With what you have provided, I cannot duplicate the problem:  http://ideone.com/8wbCqz

Comment: Well, it's most probably system and compiler dependent programming error that won't show all the time. That's why I'm rather interested in possible causes of this behaviour, since nothing comes to my mind other than memory curruption, not really looking for an exact solution. You know, maybe somebody else have seen similar.

Comment: Also, divide-by-zero in IEEE754 returns an Inf, save for 0.0/0.0.

Comment: @LThode The difference between NaN and Inf (in this circumstance) is minute.  Both are going to throw a math exception, and both are the result of bad input somewhere along the way.

Comment: @ZacHowland: NaN's are much more infectious than infinities, and they also are an indication of a much more serious screwup -- there is code that legitimately generates infinities as part of its algorithm, but that's not nearly as true for NaN.

Comment: @LThode I specified "in this circumstance" - you are speaking in general.